# imprimir int por medio de funcion con parametro string

Tags: c++, linux

No puedo imprimir la propiedad `nivel` de la estructura `deportes` porque falla o imprime caracteres raros, intente sumando la variable a la cadena, también  con `(string)d[i].nivel`.

Otro problema es que no me funciona `to_string` me aparece como si no estuviera declarada, pero si estoy utilizando la libreria string.

Trabajo en linux con g++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

const int CERO = 0;

struct deportes{
    string nombre;
    string descripcion;
    int nivel;
    deportes(){
        nombre = "";
        descripcion = "";
        nivel = 0;
    }
};

void imprima(string str){
    cout<< str << endl;
}

int main(void){
    int tamano = CERO;

    imprima("favor ingrese cuantos deportes va guardar");
    cin>> tamano;
    vector<deportes> d (tamano);    

    for (int i = CERO; i < d.size(); ++i)
    {
        imprima("ingrese el nombre del deporte");
        cin>> d[i].nombre;  
        imprima("ingrese la descripcion del deporte");  
        cin>> d[i].descripcion; 
        imprima("ingrese el nivel del deporte");    
        cin>> d[i].nivel;   
    }

    for (int i = CERO; i < d.size(); ++i)
    {   
        imprima("esta es la informacion del su deporte:");
        imprima("nombre:\t" + d[i].nombre);
        imprima("descripcion:\t" + d[i].descripcion);
        imprima("nivel");
        imprima(d[i].nivel);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No puedo imprimir la propiedad `nivel` de la estructura `deportes` porque falla o imprime caracteres raros, intente sumando la variable a la cadena, también  con `(string)d[i].nivel`.

[Elenasys](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/8175/2742) ha dado en el clavo, el problema reside en la función `imprima` cuyo parámetro de entrada es un objeto de tipo `std::string`; cuando se pasa un `int` (que es el tipo de `deportes::nivel`) falla porque `std::string` no es construible a través de un `int` ([aquí](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) puedes consultar el constructor).

Una solución, tal y como ya se ha propuesto, es transformar `deportes::nivel` a `std::string` antes de pasarlo a la función, pero otra solución sería transformar la función en plantilla:

```
template <typename TIPO>
void imprima(const TIPO valor) {
    cout << valor << endl;
}
```

De esta manera, la función podría aceptar cualquier tipo y pasarlo a `std::cout` ya que `std::cout` sabe cómo imprimir enteros y habías perdido esta flexibilidad al crear `imprima` para recibir un sólo tipo de parámetro. Con este cambio no necesitarías usar `std::to_string` ni transformar las entradas de tipo `int` a objetos `std::string`. He usado tipo constante porque asumo que una función para imprimir datos no va a modificar el valor a imprimir (que tiene poco sentido al recibirlo por copia).

Puede llevarse la función `imprima` un poco más allá y crear una versión para imprimir `deportes`:

```
void imprima(const deportes &valor){
    imprima("esta es la informacion del su deporte:");
    imprima("nombre:\t" + valor.nombre);
    imprima("descripcion:\t" + valor.descripcion);
    imprima("nivel");
    imprima(valor.nivel);
}
```

Y se puede usar así:

```
for (unsigned i = CERO; i < d.size(); ++i)
{   
    imprima(d[i]);
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando [[aquí]](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/7sv8Bb9FH9OFsbjM).

Como comentario final, te propongo unos cambios para `deportes`:

- No uses el plural, cada instancia de `deportes` guarda un solo deporte, no varios; reserva el plural para colecciones no para elementos individuales.
- No necesitas inicializar los `std::string` en el constructor, ya disponen de constructor por defecto que los deja vacíos.
- Usa la [lista de inicialización del constructor](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) en lugar de inicializar en el cuerpo del constructor:

---

```
struct deporte{
    string nombre;
    string descripcion;
    int nivel;
    deportes() : nivel(0) {
    }
};
```

Asumo que no dispones de un compilador de C++11, pero si dispusieras de él podrías cambiar tu estructura `deportes` así:

```
struct deporte{
    string nombre = "";
    string descripcion = "";
    int nivel = 0;
};

struct deporte{
    string nombre{};
    string descripcion{};
    int nivel{0};
};
```

---

PD: Elenasys también acertó en cuanto a la ausencia de `std::to_string` según el compilador que uses.

#### Editado:

> imprime caracteres raros

Apuesto a que te imprime *caracteres raros* cuando llamas a tu versión de `imprima` haciendo una transformación explícita de `deportes::nivel` a `std::string`, es decir, cuando llamas a dicha función así:

```
imprima((string)d[i].nivel);
```

Esa operación es un disparate de dimensiones bíblicas, ya que un entero no es ni será un `std::string` ni aún con la transformación explicita, pero así se lo estás haciendo creer a `imprima` que... hace lo que puede.

Como analogía te diré que le estás pasando a un piloto de F1 un lápiz diciéndole que es un coche de carreras, el piloto sostiene el lápiz y hace lo que puede: intenta cambiar de marcha, acelerar, frenar pero nada de eso funciona porque un lápiz carece de todas las características que hace que un coche de carreras sea coche de carreras.

Sucede lo mismo al pasarle un entero a `imprima` diciéndole que es un `std::string`; una de las cosas que contiene el `std::string` es un puntero a la cadena de caracteres manejada por el objeto, puntero del que carece un `int` de la misma manera que un lápiz carece de acelerador... pero la función hace lo que puede y se cree que ese entero es un `std::string`, así que al pasarle este falso `std::string` a `std::cout` éste busca el puntero en el espacio de memoria del reinterpretado `std::string` y muestra el contenido de dicho puntero, que apuntará a memoria al azar y contendrá "*caracteres raros*", eso en el mejor de los casos, también podrías haber causado un acceso inválido a memoria o [demonios podrían haber salido volando de tus fosas nasales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

La transformación de tipo que has usado se conoce como "conversión de tipos al estilo C", y es la más peligrosa de todas las conversiones permitidas en C++ ya que permite hacer conversiones ilegales como la que has usado para llamar a `imprima`. En lugar de la conversión estilo C deberías usar `static_cast`, de haber usado esa conversión el propio compilador te habría avisado de que la conversión es ilegal con un fallo de compilación:

```
imprima(static_cast<string>(d[i].nivel)); // <--- error de compilacion!
```

#### Editado (2):

> gracias por la respuesta, leí sobre lo que comento y solo me queda una duda `for (unsigned i = CERO; i < d.size(); ++i)` por que se utiliza unsigned ¿por ser un tipo más pequeño que int?

Declarar una variable como `unsigned` es el equivalente a declararla como `unsigned int` (puedes ver los tipos fundamentales en este enlace, [en el apartado *integer types* verás lo que digo](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types#Integer_types)) así que el tamaño de `unsigned` es exáctamente el mismo que el de `int`, pero el rango de números que puede usar es diferente.

En la mayoría de arquitecturas los enteros (`int`) tanto con signo (`signed`) como sin signo (`unsigned`) tienen un tamaño de 32 bits; esto significa que pueden almacenar dos elevado a trenta y dos números, que son las combinaciones posibles de sus 32 bits (`2^32 = 4'294'967'296`).

- Cuando el entero es **sin** signo, los números que puede representar van desde el `0` al `4'294'967'295`.
- Cuando el entero es **con** signo, los números que puede representar se reparten entre negativos y positivos más o menos mitad y mitad según el tipo de codificación que se use, por ejemplo desde `-2'147'483'648` a `2'147'483'647`.

Como puedes ver, no es un tema de tamaño de tipos, así que ¿por qué escogí `unsigned` para el tipo del contador del bucle? Por coherencia y para evitar conversiones.

- **Coherencia**: La cantidad de elementos almacenada por un contenedor de datos **NUNCA** es negativa; así que no tiene sentido utilizar una variable con signo como índice de un contenedor.
- **Evitar conversiones**: El tipo de retorno de [`std::vector::size`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) es un tipo sin signo, en concreto `std::vector::size_type` que suele ser un alias de [`std::size_t`](http://es.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t) el cuál es un tipo entero **sin** signo; según la plataforma `std::size_t` puede ser de 32 o de 64 bits.

Dado que `std::size_t` puede ser de 32 o de 64 bits, mi estrategia con el bucle puede no evitar conversiones de tipos en algunas plataformas, las maneras más correctas de adaptarse a los tipos serían:

```
for (decltype(d.size()) i{}; i < d.size(); ++i)
    // ....

for (vector<deportes>::size_type i{}; i < d.size(); ++i)
    // ....

for (const auto &deporte : d)
    // ....
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta,  leí sobre lo que comento y solo me queda una duda `for (unsigned i = CERO; i < d.size(); ++i)` por que se utiliza unsigned ¿por ser un tipo más pequeño que int?

Answer (score 1):

El método `imprima()` debe recibir un valor tipo string por esa razón marca error, seguramente estas usando una versión anterior a **C++ 11** por esa razón no puedes usar `std::to_string`; puedes realizar la conversión de esta forma para imprimir el valor del nivel:

```
#include <sstream>
...
...
     int iNivel = d[i].nivel;;
     string s;
     stringstream out;
     out << iNivel;
     s = out.str();
     imprima(s);
```

agrego el código completo:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

const int CERO = 0;

struct deportes{
    string nombre;
    string descripcion;
    int nivel;
    deportes(){
        nombre = "";
        descripcion = "";
        nivel = 0;
    }
};

void imprima(string str){
    cout<< str << endl;
}

int main(void){
    int tamano = CERO;

    imprima("favor ingrese cuantos deportes va guardar");
    cin>> tamano;
    vector<deportes> d (tamano);

    for (int i = CERO; i < d.size(); ++i)
    {
        imprima("ingrese el nombre del deporte");
        cin>> d[i].nombre;
        imprima("ingrese la descripcion del deporte");
        cin>> d[i].descripcion;
        imprima("ingrese el nivel del deporte");
        cin>> d[i].nivel;
    }

    for (int i = CERO; i < d.size(); ++i)
    {
        imprima("esta es la informacion del su deporte:");
        imprima("nombre:\t" + d[i].nombre);
        imprima("descripcion:\t" + d[i].descripcion);
        imprima("nivel");
       // imprima(d[i].nivel);
     int iNivel = d[i].nivel;;
     string s;
     stringstream out;
     out << iNivel;
     s = out.str();
     imprima(s);

    }
}
```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta